# Unexpected behavior with SimplePager

Tags: java, gwt, celllist, simplepager

I have a SimplePager in UiBinder (GWT 2.4):

```
    <c:CellList addStyleNames='{style.folderscroll}' ui:field='friendCellList'
        pageSize="4" />
    <c:SimplePager ui:field="pager" location='CENTER' />
```

In the corresponding .java:

```
pager.setDisplay(friendCellList);
```

I'm seeing some expected behavior. The backing data source for the cell list only returns 10 elements, but the pager's text says "1-4 of over 10". The page buttons do not become disabled, even when I run off the end of the list.

Is there a way to remove that text entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pager displays *of over X* if you don't set the row-count as *exact*, i.e. you call `setRowCount(10, false)` from your data provider.